# Python 2.7 Image variable

Tags: python

i'd like to assign string to variable and then use it. Here is part of my code:

```
    power = input()
    if power == 1:
        mode = "CONTOUR"
    elif power == 2:
        mode = 'EDGE_ENHANCE_MORE'
    elif power == 3:
        mode = EDGE_ENHANCE
    else:
        print "Wrong option"
    try:
        img = img.filter(ImageFilter.mode)
        img.show()
    except:
        print "You should load image first"
```

none of mode option works

Comment: what do you mean the option "doesn't work"?

Comment: Probably you should put `EDGE_ENHANCE` between quotes for the sake of coherence. Are you getting a `NameError` exception?

Comment: when i tap 1, i won t compilator to use CONTOUR in place of mode,i get this kind of error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./edytor.py", line 65, in <module>
    img = img.filter(ImageFilter.mode)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'mode'

Answer (score 1):

I can catch at least two things: first a possible NameError at option 3 and second you are possibly eating an AttributeError exception.

A catch-all `except` clause is a code smell, it will mask the real cause of the error condition. Instead, try to limit the `except` to exceptions you are expecting or print the exception so it will hint you about the real problem.

Try this:

```
power = input()
if power == 1:
    mode = "CONTOUR"
elif power == 2:
    mode = 'EDGE_ENHANCE_MORE'
elif power == 3:
    mode = "EDGE_ENHANCE"
else:
    print "Wrong option"
try:
    img = img.filter(getattr(ImageFilter, mode))
except Exception as e:
    print "Ooops! Got a '{}' exception ({})".format(type(e), str(e))
else:
    img.show()
```

[update]

> when i tap 1, i won t compilator to use CONTOUR in place of mode,i get this kind of error: Traceback (most recent call last): File "./edytor.py", line 65, in  img = img.filter(ImageFilter.mode) AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'mode'

Yes, as I suspected. This will try to access a attribute called 'mode' in the `ImageFilter` module (and since the module has no `mode` attribute, you get the `AttributeError`):

```
ImageFilter.mode
```

You don't want that. Instead, you want `ImageFilter.CONTOUR`. So how do you call an attribute dynamically in Python if all you have is its name stored in a variable? Something like `ImageFilter[mode]` work in Javascript but not in Python. Well, easy enough, in Python you must use `getattr`:

```
getattr(ImageFilter, "CONTOUR")
```